# Travel to Italy

Tags: air-travel

Good morning. I am a dual national with Pakistani and Italian nationality. My Italian passport expired in 2019.

I want to travel to Italy. What is the best way to travel to Italy without renewing my Italian passport?

Please help me because there is a long queue at the embassy to renew the passport.

Comment: Perhaps ask for some sort of fast processing - you'll need to check with the embassy for that. If that's not possible and you have some sort of emergency, consider an emergency passport (though I'm not sure how that works for dual nationals).

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend trying to travel to Italy on an expired passport, as they will likely not let you board your flight. A few questions for you - is renewing your passport the only option, or is it possible to get some sort of travel document as an EU citizen? You might also look into getting an emergency travel document from the Italian consulate.

As for other options, you may be able to enter Italy using just your Pakistani passport if you can provide documentation of your Italian citizenship once you arrive. But it could cause delays and issues at the border.

Comment: If they don't have a visa, the airline will not let them board on their PAK passport at all

Comment: @NicolasFormichella are you sure? An expired passport is still proof of citizenship. Or at least proof that you had citizenship until the expiry date. I wouldn't be surprised if the airline accepted that as proof of right of entry.

Comment: You both make good points. It does seem risky to try flying on an expired passport. I wonder, since OP is an Italian citizen, if contacting the consulate is the best bet. They may be able to issue temporary docs or advise the safest way to travel. Maybe a stop there before flying could help clear things up at the border.